# Scaffolding entity relationships with MVC5 EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im learning MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6. How can i make the model support relationships between my classes. Like a one Employee can have several Tasks. Is it possible to make the scaffolding set it up automagically?

Ive read some similar tutorials for earlier versions but they dont seem to apply. So i ask for answers from someone who has experience of MVC5 with EF6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code to base this on, here's all you really have to do to set up a one-to-many relationship in EF6:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Employee AssignedEmployee { get; set; } //Not required, but it would be nice to easily access the owner of a task from code.
    [ForeignKey("AssignedEmployee ")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; } //Also not required, but comes in handy often. Just holds the ID of the assigned employee. I always include this, but it's just a preference.
}
```

Just remember to add these to classes as properties to your EF context. This is a simple example, since you're not very specific with what you want to achieve. :)

Comment: If i would scaffold that, would it set up how to choose an employee when adding a task? what im trying to do is to make sense of the scaffolding cause i can only get it to set up simple properties not my own types. And i cant see how scaffolding would be usefull if it doesnt support it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The scaffolding is a nice feature, but it can only do so much. If you were to scaffold, say, a create task view, the scaffolding engine would create an editor for EmployeeID, wherein you can write the ID of the employee in question. This is of course not a nice user experience, so normally, this would be achieved, for example, with a drop down list, where you pick the employee. The scaffolding engine cannot do this for you, but it is not hard to achieve on your own.

Comment: Thanks! Then i know where to go. :)